# npm Bonjour not finding services on other devices on the same wifi

Tags: node.js, bonjour

Hello i am a beginner in coding, the notion of my project is to have a connection between ios and windows to be able to send file across from ios to windows, my idea to implement this would be through use of mdns to find the right service, followed by TCP, then the use of a ./ storage system to store the files on windows, currently, my problem is "npm bonjour" as currently it will not find any services that arent advertised on the same device. What i am first trying to do is a simple browser on one windows machine and then a service on another machine as seen below:

service:

```js
var bonjour = require('bonjour')()
 
// advertise an HTTP server on port 3000
bonjour.publish({ name: 'My Web Server', type: 'http', port: 3000 })
```

browser:

```
var bonjour = require('bonjour')()

bonjour.find({ type: 'http' }, function (service) {
  console.log('Found an HTTP server:', service)
})
```

So in conclusion i would first like to solve the problem of being able to find a service advertised on another windows device. Sorry if my english is bad.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the bonjour library filters a lot of services.
In particular services that are running on a different device.

See:
[https://github.com/watson/bonjour/issues/35]

I removed some parts of the filter functions in the browser part of the bonjour implementation, and was able to list services that are running on a different device.

My changes can be downloaded from the site mentioned above.